# get information from facebook graph returns undefined

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

I'm using NodeJS to get information from Facebook graph. However, sofa I have been unable to receive to the server any info aside from name and ID.
I'm using Express and fb plugin for this task.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var FB = require('fb');

var port = 1334;
var IP = '127.0.0.1';
http.createServer(function(req, res)
{ 
    callback(req, res);
}).listen(port, IP);


var FBToken = 'token was taken from facebook graph explorer';
var FBID = 'my user ID'
var FBGet = 'me?fields=name,id,gender,first_name,last_name,birthday';
// I also tried :
// var FBGet ='fields:['name','id','gender,'first_name','last_name','birthday']';

var callback = function (req,res) {
    if (req.url==='/fb'){

    FB.api(FBID, { FBGet }, function (res) {
        if(!res || res.error) {
          console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
          return;
        }
        console.log(res.id);
        console.log(res.name);
        console.log(res.gender);
        console.log(res.first_name);
        console.log(res.last_name);
        console.log(res.birthday);
        console.log(res.blah);
        console.log(res);
      });
}
```

the output is:

```
*my_name*
*my_ID*
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
Object {name: "*my_Name*", id: "*My_Id*"}
    id:"*my_ID*"
    name:"*my_Name*"
    __proto__:Object {constructor: , __defineGetter__: , __defineSetter__: , …}
    __defineGetter__:function __defineGetter__() { … }
    __defineSetter__:function __defineSetter__() { … }
    __lookupGetter__:function __lookupGetter__() { … }
    __lookupSetter__:function __lookupSetter__() { … }
```

I've granted the access token all the required permissions.
anyone knows why it restricts the data I'm asking?

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the `fb` package, but in the [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb#get) the parameters are passed via an object with an array called `fields`:

```
FB.api('4', { fields: ['id', 'name'] }, function (res) {
  if(!res || res.error) {
    console.log(!res ? 'error occurred' : res.error);
    return;
  }
  console.log(res.id);
  console.log(res.name);
});
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: yes I have, it was identical
thank you, however, I'll change the text to 'fields' so it will be more in line with the examples and more comprehensive.

The way i wrote it is the way the Facebook API Explorer gives the query link.